# How can I find nodes with specific properties?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I find nodes with specific properties using a Cypher query language? I have a list of cities. List contains city names and population. I need to print out population for one city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, first method is with WHERE clause:

```
MATCH (c:City)
WHERE c.name = "London"
RETURN c.population_size;
```

and second one is without:

```
MATCH (c:City {name: "London"})
RETURN c.population_size;
```

The result will be the same.